# Adding a flat list from a list of list into a fixed length numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-3.7

I'm trying to add a flat list from a list of list into a fixed length numpy array.

```
import numpy as np

def extract_foo(x):
    return x.size


def extract_foo_of_foo(x):
    return [x.size for _ in range(18)]


def extract_feats():
    input_array = np.ones((36,))
    output_matrix = np.empty((36, 22))

    for x_idx, x_val in enumerate(input_array):
        output_matrix[x_idx] = [
            extract_foo(x_val),
            extract_foo(x_val),
            extract_foo(x_val),
            extract_foo(x_val),

            # this is where I want to flatten my list
            # that one is a list of list containing 22 - 4 = 18 lists
            extract_foo_of_foo(x_val)
        ]

    return output_matrix
```

I have tried a list comprehension as follow :

```
[y for y in extract_foo_of_foo(x_val)]
```

And with reduce function :

```
reduce(lambda y: y, extract_foo_of_foo(x_val))
```

I am using numpy 1.17.4 and python 3.7.5. Is there a pythonic way to handle this ?

Comment: What about `[z for z in y for y in extract_foo_of_foo(x_val)]`?

Comment: @accdias You mean `[z for y in extract_foo_of_foo(np.array([1, 2, 3])) for z in y]`?

Comment: @Patol75, Yep... I messed the order. Sorry.

Comment: Hi, both solutions don't work. I get the same error :
ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 5 to array axis with dimension 22

Comment: The right one is `[z for y in extract_foo_of_foo(x_val) for z in y]`.

Comment: Do you mind providing the expected output? If you replace `np.array([1, 2, 3])` by `x_val`, you still do not get what you want?

Comment: Or `x.size` instead of `x.shape`?

Comment: @Patol75 you're right ! The correct example is with x.size instead of x.shape. I'm editing the question. Still doesn't work. The correct output there should be an array of 22 ones.

Comment: But how can you get 22 items when you are actually iterating 18 times in extract_foo_of_foo?

Comment: Pretty much unclear to me what is asked here. What do you mean by "add"? Do you mean *insert* or do you want to *replace* a part of the matrix? Specify the exact indices if so. Also, I don't see what list of lists exactly you want to flatten and insert? `x.size` gives you a scalar (product of the shape elements).

Comment: I am not sure that what I want to do is possible actually. I want to the list from `extract_foo_of_foo` one by one into `output_matrix` so I don't have to add them with an explicit for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I believe you can use slice indexing on the second axis like this:

```
def extract_feats():
    input_array = np.ones((36,))
    output_matrix = np.empty((36, 22))
    for x_idx, x_val in enumerate(input_array):
        output_matrix[x_idx, 0:4] = [
            extract_foo(x_val),
            extract_foo(x_val),
            extract_foo(x_val),
            extract_foo(x_val)
        ]
        output_matrix[x_idx, 4:22] = extract_foo_of_foo(x_val)
    return output_matrix
```

Here's the shape of the output:

```
>>> extract_feats().shape
(36, 22)
```

Comment: This is somehow the closest to what I was looking for. Thanks for your reply, I will edit the question with your solution.

Comment: It's better if you don't edit your question I think! That way if others post different solutions you can consider them instead and just accept a different answer.